# Android app in Google Play and UTM downloads traffic

Tags: android, google-play, utm

Recently UTM traffic appeared in my app downloads statistic, but I nothing paid for it. Should I worry?

Answer (score 0):

Your current earnings will get updated once in a month. If your earnings are more than the threshold, you can withdraw it.